# nVidia CUDA code doesn't work?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to klearn how to program for nVidia cards. Here is my code:

```
__global__ void add_one(int* i)
{
    i[0]++;
}

template<class TYPE>
void gpu_load(TYPE data)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &data, size * sizeof(TYPE));
}

template<class TYPE>
void copy_to_gpu(TYPE* cpu_var, TYPE* gpu_var)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMemcpy(  gpu_var, cpu_var, size * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
}

template<class TYPE>
void copy_to_cpu(TYPE* cpu_var, TYPE* gpu_var)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMemcpy( gpu_var, cpu_var, size * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

int main() 
{
    int gpu_i[1];
    int cpu_i[1];

    cpu_i[0] = 5;

    gpu_load(cpu_i);
    copy_to_gpu(cpu_i, gpu_i);

    add_one<<<1, 1>>>(gpu_i);

    int res[1];

    copy_to_cpu(res, gpu_i);

    std::cout << res[0];
}
```

Why the cout doesn't display 5+1 and displays 0 instead?

I tried my best to make it work... It seems like nothing happens...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You're passing `cpu_i` to your `cudaMalloc` routine.  This is not what you want.
- The `gpu_i` pointer needs to be something that is modifiable by your `cudaMalloc` routine, so we need to pass the address of it to that routine, as a pointer.
- You had your parameters reversed on the `copy_to_cpu` routine.

If the following code doesn't work for you, add [proper cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api).  It's possible there is a problem with your system config as well:

```
#include <iostream>

__global__ void add_one(int* i)
{
    i[0]++;
}

template<class TYPE>
void gpu_load(TYPE* &data)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &data, size * sizeof(TYPE));
}

template<class TYPE>
void copy_to_gpu(TYPE* cpu_var, TYPE* gpu_var)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMemcpy(  gpu_var, cpu_var, size * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}

template<class TYPE>
void copy_to_cpu(TYPE* cpu_var, TYPE* gpu_var)
{
    int size = 1;
    cudaMemcpy( cpu_var, gpu_var, size * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
}

int main()
{
    int *gpu_i;
    int cpu_i[1];

    cpu_i[0] = 5;

    gpu_load(gpu_i);
    copy_to_gpu(cpu_i, gpu_i);

    add_one<<<1, 1>>>(gpu_i);

    int res[1];

    copy_to_cpu(res, gpu_i);

    std::cout << res[0];
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call  gpu_load(&gpu_i); without the &?

Comment: I've modified the code to an equivalent form which does not require the `&` on the `gpu_load` parameter.

Comment: Hah, filling up to the required number of characters with exclamation marks :)

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to `cudaMemcpy` is always the destination, but in `copy_to_cpu` you pass `gpu_var` first.

Comment: Thanks, now I call it: cudaMemcpy(cpu_var, gpu_var, size * sizeof(TYPE), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); and still returns 0?

Comment: In `gpu_load` you are passing in `data`, but `cudaMalloc` writes to it and that result is then lost.

Comment: Try making it work without any of your helper functions, which are just making it harder. Once it works, then make it elegant.

Comment: Thanks, how can I get the type of a template, sizeof(TYPE) returns 8 bytes, when using it with a float.

Comment: Start by getting rid of your helper functions. They are just making it harder.